# java script calculate time difference

Tags: javascript, time

i want to let the user to input the entry and the exit time then calculate the charge base on the hours. What i think is convert the time to minutes and then calculate the difference. Can anyone teach me how to do that?

Comment: entry time and exit time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to parse your dates, e.g. in the constructor of a new Date:

```
var first = new Date(yourDateAsAString)
var second = new Date(yourOtherDateAsAString)
```

Then you are able to calculate a difference in days as follows:

```
var difference = second.getTime() - first.getTime()
```

These are the milliseconds. Do /1000 for seconds, then /60 for minutes, then /60 for hours and then /24 for the final difference in days.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var timestampEntry = new Date(entry_time).getTime();
var timestampExit = new Date(exit_time).getTime();

var delta = timestampExit - timestampEntry;
console.log(delta / 1000 / 60 / 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<input id="date1" type="text">
<input id="date2" type="text">

<button id="calculate">calculate!</button>    

<span id="result"></span>
```

javascript:

```
function calculate() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById('date1').value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById('date2').value;

    var date1 = new Date(input1);
    var date2 = new Date(input2);

    var result = (date2 - date1) / 1000 / 60 / 60;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}

document.getElementById('calculate').onclick = calculate;
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Z9dM/

Note that you need a full date, you have to know a day.

Also parsing date with the constructor of Date() doesn't work exactly the same in all browser. Be aware of the troll from a big cave.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a 24hr clock:

time = hh:mm

ex: 07:34, 23:22

```
function calculateHours(start, end) {

    var 
      startHours = parseInt(start.slice(0,2),10),
      startMin = parseInt(start.slice(2), 10),
      stopHours = parseInt(stop.slice(0,2), 10),
      stopMin = parseInt(stop.slice(2), 10),
      total
   ;

   total = ((stopHours * 60 + stopMin) - (startHours * 60 + startMin)) / 60;

   return total;
}
```

For sure there are better ways to do such a thing, but this is the function you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Although this can  be done in plain JavaScript, if you are working with and manipulating a lot of date times, you might want to look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com). It makes working with times and timezones a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thing like this, i haven't done the form validation

Here is the plunkr link: http://plnkr.co/edit/8wVC1yZeGCmrY0rSXMzL?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

JS stores dates as time in ms since midnight January 1, 1970
So calculating the time between two dates is as simple as subtracting them.

Create a Date() object at two different times.

var time1 = new Date(); 
var time2 = new Date();

var difference = time2-time1;

var inHours = difference / (1000 * 60 * 60);